# Difference between "a few minutes" and "few minutes"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, determiners

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“A few” vs. “few”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1866/a-few-vs-few)

What is the difference between "a few minutes" and "few minutes"?

For instance, how do these statements differ?

> 1. She has a few minutes before the train leaves.
> 2. She has few minutes before the train leaves.