# When should I use "a little" and when "a few"?

Tags: word-choice

> Hassan spent ages cooking it.
>   OK OK.  I'm goimg to eat ___ just to be polite.

Is that (a) *a little* or (b) *a few*?

Is there a rule to choose which word to use?

Comment: Depends on what's to be eaten. Exam questions are OT, though.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: You would use "a few" countable items, but "a little" of an uncountable.

Comment: Answered at [“A few” vs. “few”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1866/a-few-vs-few/144895#144895).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Which of the answers there answer this question?

Comment: 'I have a lot of friends.' and likewise 'I have a few friends.' [Countable noun]

'I have a lot of money.' ... 'I have a little money.' [Uncountable noun]'. 'It' in this question must have an antecedent which will inform which answer fits.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 
 
Writing *countable* and *uncountable* next to an example used for entirely different purposes is not giving an answer to this question here, really, I don't think. Apart from that, the item may well be countable, but if someone asked *did you eat the item?* and you said *well, I ate a little* (of the item), that would be grammatical and *I ate a few* would not (with that intended meaning).

Comment: There is nothing at all "ungrammatical" in "I ate a few."  It may not make sense in a given context, but it is still valid grammar.

Comment: @Hot Licks Yes; were the question not off-topic for other reasons, it would need more context to be provided.

Answer (score 3):

If the thing(s) being eaten are grammatically plural use *a few*, otherwise use *a little*:

> I ate a little cake.
>
> I ate a few cakes.

In the Original Poster's example, however, *a little* is being used in a fused Determiner-Head construction. It is being used as a Determiner without any following noun, in a similar way to how we use pronouns. The antecedent for *a little* is the word *it* from the first speaker's sentence:

> A: Hassan spent ages cooking **it**.
>
> B: OK, OK. I'll eat **a little**, just to be polite.

Notice that if speaker A had said *them* instead of *it*, then speaker B would most likely have said *a few*:

> A: Hassan spent ages cooking **them**.
>
> B: OK, OK. I'll eat **a few**, just to be polite.

Comment: Any feedback on the driveby downvote? I can't improve my post without it ....

Comment: Sorry; I had to rush off to a celebratory meal. // 'If the thing(s) being eaten are grammatically plural use _a few_, otherwise use _a little_' leads to 'I had a little hot dog'. Etic, formal and concord-dictating singularity / plurality need distinguishing. But, using the usual analysis,   'a little' (quantifier sense) is used with non-count usages and 'a few' with count usages, as the answer I linked to observed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "I had a little hot dog" is perfectly grammatical, though, even if a bit ambiguous. It's perfectly apt if you only had a little of someone else's hotdog (see what I did there- and notice the complete singularity of the given hotdog). The linked to answer may *mention* countability, but involves no *explanation* - which isn't surprising, because it wasn't aiming to answer this question! Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: Typical case.  This is essentially an opinion and 'comments' is the place for it. There's a need for a canonical basis to be shown. Not down voting just yet. Cf. Edwin Ashworth above.