# Why are "quite few" and "quite a few" opposites?

Tags: meaning, grammar

Consider these two sentences:

- How many people came?  **Quite few**.
- How many people came?  **Quite a few**.

The first means few people came (less than expected), the second means many (more than expected).  Why the difference, and what exactly is the "a" referring to?

Comment: See this [similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1866/a-few-vs-few)

Comment: That question is indeed similar (thanks!), but the focus is on explaining the difference in meaning, not *why* that little article makes such a difference.

Comment: The article makes the use of 'few' as a singular instance of a plural noun.  Then, the adverb 'quite' serves to multiply the noun: "A limited number in a considerable extent".  The limited number is repeated which add up to many.  Without the article the adverb intensifies the noun: "A limited number  to an extreme".   Great question.

Comment: I won't post this as an 'answer' as I've only anecdotal evidence. Both these expressions use the moderately emphasising ('rather') sense of 'quite'. 'Quite few' is then transparent. 'A few' means 'not many', but the British penchant for showing reserve also makes use of 'a few' ironically to mean 'quite a lot'. 'Quite a few' then appears on the scene to disambiguate.

Comment: Because _few_ and _a few_ are opposites. _Few_ is a negative trigger, whereas _a few_ means 'at least some', a positive rather than negative quantifier. Consequently 'quite a few' means more than that, and is even more positive, but 'quite few' simply emphasizes the negative direction.

Comment: @JohnLawler That sounds like a fine answer to me!