# Quantifiers like few, a few, etc

Tags: grammar, adjectives, sentence, quantifiers

I came across a question in my book of whose answer I did not find satisfactory. Please help me

Q) Improve the bracketed part of the sentence.

The guest stood quietly for (few moments).

The answer given is:
“Few moments” will be replaced with “a few moments”.

My question is:
Is Using “few moments”, i.e. without improvement, not assumed correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["A few" vs. "few"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1866/a-few-vs-few) But 'for a few minutes / hours / days / weeks / years / moments ...' are acceptable prepositional phrases showing duration, whereas 'for few minutes / hours / days / weeks / years / moments ...' are not.

Comment: _Few_ is a negative word; it means less than some expected number and can govern negative polarity items like _ever_ and _at all_. _A few_, however, is not negative and means a small but definitely positive number. In the book example, there's no special minimum time for the guest to stand quietly, so _few_ doesn't make sense, but _a few_ does.